# Using Proguard with a runnable JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, proguard

I am trying to create a runable JAR file using proguard. When I export the JAR using Eclipse everything works fine and I have a nice JAR file.

To obfusicate I use the command line and the command

```
java -jar ${ANDROID_SDK}/lib/proguard.jar @proguard-project.txt
```

But then when I try to run the created JAR I get the response

```
no main manifest attribute
```

My proguard-project.txt is as follows

```
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes_processed.jar
-libraryjars proguard/android.jar

-dontwarn java.**
-keep class java.**

-dontwarn javax.**
-keep class javax.**

-dontwarn android.**
-keep class android.**

-dontwarn com.sun.**
-keep class com.sun.**

-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn java.beans.Beans
-dontwarn javax.security.**
-keep class javamail.** {*;}
-keep class javax.mail.** {*;}
-keep class javax.activation.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.dsn.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.handlers.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.smtp.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.util.** {*;}
-keep class mailcap.** {*;}
-keep class mimetypes.** {*;}
-keep class myjava.awt.datatransfer.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.awt.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.misc.** {*;}

-dontnote


-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class com.app.main {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ProGuard does not generate a manifest itself.
You will have to create one manually, and include it like this in your configuration:

```
-injars path/to/your/resources-dir
-injars ...
```

The resource-dir should include the manifest using the following directory structure:

```
META-INF/Manifest.MF
```

If you also obfuscate the main class of the jar, you will need to add the following configuration:

```
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.MF
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, I tried this but  I still get the same result. I tried it with and without obfuscating the main class but it did produce different results.
Before I obfuscate my manifest.mf file looks like

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: com.app.main

After I obfuscate and I use winrar to extract the JAR and open the manifest.mf file it now looks like 

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_95 (Oracle Corporation)

Comment: Ah I have just found my Manifest.MF at the top level of the extract JAR, not in the META-INF folder - could this be a problem?

Comment: yes, this has to be in the META-INF directory, otherwise it is not recognized as a valid manifest. I forgot to mention this, so you will need an -injars path/to/your/resource directory instead, which contains the META-INF/Manifest.MF file in the expected directory structure.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply, I can now see the Manifest.MF file in the META-INF folder when I extract the jar, however I'm still getting the error _no_ _main_ _manifest_ _attribute_

Comment: Did you add the Main-Class attribute (see here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)?

Comment: Yes my Manifest.MF is :

'Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: com.app.main'

Where my main class has the public static void main(String[] arg) method and is under src>com.app

Comment: I guess the filename of the manifest has to be all uppercase: MANIFEST.MF

Comment: When I put it al in uppercase I got a warning about there being a duplicate MANIFEST.MF file to I added (!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) after each -injar ** and -libraryjar ** , and now it works !! well I'm now getting an error in my code due to the obfuscating but that should be simply enough to fix